# std::map iterate through keys with index of key

Tags: c++

I need to iterate through the keys of a map, but looking ahead to future keys. For example:

```
map<int, int> m;
vector<int> v;
for(map<int,int>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
  cout << it->first << "\n";
  //is the next element equal to 3?
  auto next = it++;
  std::cout << "equals 3" << next==3 << std::endl
}
```

but sometimes I don't want to see the next element (n+1), maybe I want to see the n+10 element, etc. How do I do this? If my list has 100 elements, and I arrive at element 99, then 99+10 is gonna break evrything. Is there a way to test if my iterator can achieve n+10?

The best solution I thougth of is to keep track of an index `i` and see if I can call `it + 10` (that is, if `i+10<mapSize`). Bus is there a more elegant way? Maybe testing if the `n+10` iterator exists or something?

Comment: Note that the `iterator` of `std::map` is of type [LegacyBidirectionalIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator) which doesn't support random access (such as `it + 10`), only increment and decrement (although you can get away with just calling `++` 10 times). What do you do if you can't look ahead 10 elements? This smells like an XY problem.

Comment: @John what's an XY problem?

Comment: [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: In this case, what are you trying to do on a higher level? There's a feeling it can be approached in a different way.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs You haven't accepted an answer to the latest 15 questions you've asked. I didn't read the questions/answers, but it is an unusual streak.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I was going to accept, I just tend to give time for people to write.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm trying to calculate a volume of tetrahedrons formed by lots of arbitrary points in space but I want to skip some because there are many, so I want to jump in 10 by 10 or 50 by 50 etc

Comment: Why not use a `std::vector`? It's designed for that sort of thing.

Comment: That does sound like a `vector`. What's the `map` buy you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map does not sound like the appropiate data type for your use case. Try switching to a container that supports random access

Comment: Why not? You can use any container. See my answer.

Comment: @ArminMontigny You _can_ use any container and `std::advance` - but using `std::advance` is costly on container types where stepping can't be done in constant time (`n+10000` takes the same time as `n+1`). `map` and `list` etc. are therefore not good candidates if stepping needs to be done a lot and needs to be fast.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your are looking for something like `std::advance` (Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance)), but with an additional check, if the advance operation was past the end or not.

We can use a small lambda to do this kind of check. Since it uses only an increment operation, it should work for all type of containers.

Please see the following example to illustrate the function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>

using Type = std::map<int, int>;
using TypeIter = Type::iterator;

int main() {
    // Lambda to advance a container iterator and check, if that was possible
    auto advanceAndCheck = [](const Type& t, const TypeIter& ti, size_t advance) -> std::pair<bool, TypeIter>
        { TypeIter i{ ti }; while ((i != t.end()) && (advance--)) ++i;  return { i != t.end(), i }; };


    // Test data
    Type m{ {1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}, {4,4}, {5,5} , {6,6} };

    // Iterate over container
    for (TypeIter it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {

        // Show some values
        std::cout << it->first << "\n";

        // Test
        {
            // Advance and check
            auto [OK, itn] = advanceAndCheck(m, it, 1);
            if (OK && itn->first == 3) std::cout << "The next Element is 3\n";
        }
        {
            // Advance and check
            auto [OK, itn] = advanceAndCheck(m, it, 5);
            if (OK && itn->first == 6) std::cout << "The 5th next Element is 6\n";
        }
    }
}
```